# Apache: Rewriting URL; removing filename and file extension from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I know this question has been asked here very often. However when I try any solution I've found, I either get an error that the URL was not found or I get no change of the URL at all.

Linux Version: Red Hat 4.8.5-4

Apache Version: 2.4.6 (CentOS)

Python Version: 3.5.2

My httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/home/deev/webapps/workload/apache2"

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/deev/logs/user/access_workload.log combined
ErrorLog /home/deev/logs/user/error_workload.log

DirectoryIndex index.py
DocumentRoot /home/deev/webapps/workload/htdocs

Listen 23805
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 5
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 3
ThreadsPerChild 5

WSGIDaemonProcess workload processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/deev/webapps/workload/lib/python3.5
WSGIProcessGroup workload
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On

WSGIPythonPath /home/deev/webapps/workload/htdocs/
WSGIScriptAlias /index /home/deev/webapps/workload/htdocs/index.py
#WSGIScriptAlias / /index

<Directory /home/deev/webapps/workload/htdocs>
    # enabeling .htaccess file
    AllowOverride All
    # activating mod_rewrite for this dir
    RewriteEngine on 
    # setting the base URL for rewrites to / or the root dir for the website (home/deev/webapps/workload/htdocs/ == /)
    RewriteBase /
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess (in the root dir of my website):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.py [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.py/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.py/$1 [L]
```

I don't have any experience with this language and wanted to solve this problem quickly so that I could move on with python, but it seems rather difficult for me. Also, if in the httpd.conf file I change the WSGIScriptAlias from "/index" to "/" I receive the Errorpage:

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.